# Node resize image with url without saving image

Tags: node.js, image, image-resizing

I have a service that takes a FB image url as a param, checks it is a valid url that returns an image and then returns the url if all checks have passed. I would like to add a step to resize the image if those params are also passed in, and then return the resized image via url as I did before.

My experience with image manipulation is minimal to say the least, but my understanding so far is to use a library such as sharp, resize it, save the newly sized image somewhere and then return the new url to the image location.

That seems to be the most logical approach. But, I'm wondering what a possible solution would be if I do not want to host these resized images anywhere. Is there another way, or is my previous understanding on track with the way to go?

Example url from facebook would look like: `https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/16473924_10154471006092746_6242863207915608429_n.jpg?oh=4d7fb8fb162c0ff036810ee2969703f0&oe=5A25EE1C`.

Comment: It makes no sense to resize an image, throw the resized image away and then return a URL to get the image.  When the URL is requested, you will just have to create the image again so you can return it.  So, it is completely unclear to me what you are really asking for help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the comment. I thought my disclosure of my image manipulation experience was enough, along with the fact that I outlined what my logical solution was, but wondered if there was something that could be done that I am not aware of, given my experience with image manipulation. That said, to be completely clear, an answer could be either a) yes, your previous understanding is on track as there is no other alternative or b) try this alternative. SO is an awesome place to converse and learn, and that is what I am trying to do. Apologies if you feel it is a silly question.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand what you are asking.  If nobody else comes along to help, it's probably because they don't understand what the question is.  I was hoping you would edit the question to make it a lot clearer what you are asking for help with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the questions title :

> Node resize image with url without saving image

I think that you are trying to manipulate an image based upon a request to your 'service', and then send it back post-processed without having to store it and use disk space...

## [`JIMP`] fetch, resize and return an image without saving to disk:

This example on requesting the server root '/', it fetches an image, resizes it and sends it back as a response without having to store it in disk.

```
const imgURL = "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg";
const express = require('express'); const app = express()
var Jimp = require("jimp")
app.get('/',function(req, res){
  Jimp.read(imgURL, function(err,img){
    if (err) throw err;
    img.resize(32, 32).getBase64( Jimp.AUTO , function(e,img64){
        if(e)throw e
        res.send('<img src="'+img64+'">')
    });
  });
});
app.listen(3000);
```